# How to properly insert a background image

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, subview, layer

I use this code to set a background image. The only problem is that it covers everything I insert in the XIB file. What should I do to ensure that my textfields, buttons, etc. are also visible (in front of the background). Thanks for your help!

```
// Setup the background
UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:background];
[background release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UIImageView *background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
>       [self.view addSubview:background];
>   [self sendSubviewToBack:background];
>       [background release];

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. In the third line, there is a typo though. The beginning of the line should say "self.view" instead of just "self". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an XIB, then just make sure that all of your objects are above the `UIImageView`.

Alternatively, you can use `colorWithPatternImage:`

```
UIImage * bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
[myView_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: bg]];
```

Comment: Thanks, what exactly should I type in myView? self? Thanks!

Comment: What ever your main `viewController` is that your objects sit on.